# Error on append string - Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, string, string-literals, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to formulate a data matrix into a string to send to the server. But I get an error when apending data to a string. Why is this happening ?

The data I'm trying to send is the Bitmap image pixels.

My code:

```
string getPixelsFromBitmap(Bitmap& bitmap) {
    //Pass up the width and height, as these are useful for accessing pixels in the vector o' vectors.
    int width = bitmap.GetWidth();
    int height = bitmap.GetHeight();

    auto* bitmapData = new Gdiplus::BitmapData;

    //Lock the whole bitmap so we can read pixel data easily.
    Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, width, height);
    bitmap.LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat32bppARGB, bitmapData);

    //Get the individual pixels from the locked area.
    auto* pixels = static_cast<unsigned*>(bitmapData->Scan0);

    //Vector of vectors; each vector is a column.
    //std::vector<std::vector<unsigned>> resultPixels(width, std::vector<unsigned>(height));

    //todo fix string 
    string matrix("");

    const int stride = abs(bitmapData->Stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            //Get the pixel colour from the pixels array which we got earlier.
            const unsigned pxColor = pixels[y * stride / 4 + x];

            //Get each individual colour component. Bitmap colours are in reverse order.
            const unsigned red = (pxColor & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
            const unsigned green = (pxColor & 0xFF00) >> 8;
            const unsigned blue = pxColor & 0xFF;

            //Combine the values in a more typical RGB format (as opposed to the bitmap way).
            const int rgbValue = RGB(red, green, blue);

            //Assign this RGB value to the pixel location in the vector o' vectors.
            //resultPixels[x][y] = rgbValue;

            matrix += string(rgbValue + ",");
        }
        matrix += string(".");
    }
    //Unlock the bits that we locked before.
    bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: `matrix += string(rgbValue + ",");` -> `matrix += to_string(rgbValue) + ",";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
matrix += string(rgbValue + ",");
```

the argument expression represents an expression with the pointer arithmetic, To the pointer expression of the type `const char *` (`","`) is added the integer value `rgbValue` that evidently results in accessing a memory beyond the string literal `","`.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
matrix += string( std::to_string( rgbValue ) + ",");
```